# What are some examples of reforms to Hangul proposed in the past?

Tags: hangul, orthography

Wikipedia mentions how historically, several spelling changes and even new characters were proposed for Hangul. What other changes have been suggested throughout the history of Korea?

Comment: Do you have any specific question?

Comment: This is a list question.  These are not normally a good fit for SE sites.

Answer (score 4):

**Horizontal writing (가로쓰기)** and **spacing (띄어쓰기)**. It was not a thing.

Also, **breaking syllable blocks up** just like when you write Latin alphabets (풀어쓰기) was suggested -- not adopted though. Like writing "ㅎㅏㄱㄱㅛ" instead of "학교."

Another suggestion, in 1954, was [**simplified Hangul orthography**](https://theme.archives.go.kr/next/hangeulPolicy/plan.do) where you write 갓 instead of 같, 갇, 갓 as they make the same sound -- not adopted as well.

---

### Horizontal writing and spacing

Actually, *horizontal writing* and *spacing* are pretty recent adoptions that made into the Korean orthography [in the late nineteenth century by the Scottish missionary John Ross](https://www.hangeul.go.kr/user/html/webzine/201702/sub2.html) translating the Bible into Korean. He also published “[*Corean Primer*](https://archive.org/details/coreanprimerbein00rossrich),” the Korean language textbook where *horizontal writing* and *spacing* were introduced, in 1877.

[image: The cover]
[image: Introduction]

> 7. The Corean alphabet, though always in syllables, is written, not from left to right as here, but from top to bottom and right to left, like Chinese; ….

[image: Lesson Ⅰ]

> #### Lesson Ⅰ — Library.
>
> ‍ ᄂᆡ<sub>/ne/ “I”</sub> 되션<sub>/deoshun/ “Corean”</sub> 말<sub>/mal/ “words”</sub> 보이고쟈<sub>/bo-ighojia/ “(to) learn”</sub> 한다<sub>/handa/ “want.”</sub>
>
> ‍ 네<sub>/nê/ “You”</sub> 나를<sub>/narul/ “(for) me”</sub> 션ᄉᆡᆼ<sub>/shiungseng/ “teacher”</sub> ᄃᆡ졉<sub>/dejiup/ “engage,”</sub> 하갓너니<sub>/haghannuni./ “will?”</sub>
>
> ᄂᆡ<sub>/ne/ “I”</sub> ᄃᆡ졉<sub>/dejiup/ “engage,”</sub> 히<sub>/ha/</sub>올리<sub>/ōri./ “can.”</sub>
>
> ‍ 얼 ᄆᆡ나<sub>/ulmena/ “How much”</sub> 주갓슴마<sub>/dsooghasumma./ “give him?”</sub>
>
> 힌<sub>/han/ “One”</sub> 달에<sub>/dalê/ “moon”</sub> 넉<sub>/nugh/ “four”</sub>냥<sub>/niang./ “taels.”</sub>
>
> 됴운<sub>/dio-oon/ “Good”</sub> 션ᄉᆡᆼ은<sub>/shiunshengun/ “teacher”</sub> 맛망이<sub>/matdangi/ “should”</sub> ᄃᆡ구말<sub>/degoogmal/ “Chinese speech”</sub> 암머니<sub>/ammuni/ “know.”</sub>
>
> ‍ 되션<sub>/doeshun/ “Corean”</sub>말<sub>/mal/ “speech”</sub> 보이기<sub>/boigi/ “(to) learn”</sub> 쉽다<sub>/sooipda/ “easy.”</sub>